# Why does the app icon nt show when switching apps

Tags: ios, swift

I am unsure why this icon is not showing when I am testing the app on iOS.
I am wondering have I missed a step?

[image: my App not showing icon]

[image: Assets - icon]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the device/simulator, clearing derived data etc. It's possible that iOS uses a cached version of your icon.

Comment: Yep restart the device fixed it

Answer (score 0):

For app icon, icon sizes are very important. If you provide any size that not same as required then the icons are not showing properly. Read this document you will understand about app icon sizes.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/

```
180px × 180px (60pt @3x)
120px × 120px (60pt @2x)

40px × 40px (20pt @2x)
20px × 20px (20pt @1x)
```

This link will help to create different size of icons you need.
https://makeappicon.com/